# Is there way to use Drupal menu's "page arguments" in the "access callback" function?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-routes

Is there way to use Drupal menu's "page arguments" in the "access callback" function?
I need to use both 'access arguments' and 'access callback'

> > 'page arguments' => array(3, 4),
> >
> > 'access arguments' => array('access mymodule data'),
> >
> > 'access callback' => 'mymodule_application_page_access',

Is it possible to use values passed as "page arguments" in my "access callback" method - mymodule_application_page_access ?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do:

```
    $menu['mymodule/path1/path2/%/%'] = array(
         //.... some stuff
        'page callback' => 'mymodule_somecallback',
        'page arguments' => array(3, 4),
        'access arguments' => array('access mymodule data',3,4),
        'access callback' => 'mymodule_application_page_access',
        //.... some more stuff
   );
```

Comment: Thanks skarist!
I tried that earlier but got an error and then I realized I had considered only 2 arguments instead of 3 in the access callback method! My mistake :)